# Q: Looking for a solution to autorun AWS CLi commands using batch files

Tags: batch-file, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking for a good way to auto deploy projects using the AWS command line that is provided, like the AWS Beanstalk.

Basically my idea is to create a server of some sort to execute specialized batch files to run the command line when given the right instruction and parameters.

I was wondering if there is a solution already existing that I can purchase or adopt instead of re-inventing the wheel on my end.

I would appreciate any resource or ideas on this. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Why go primitive?`:)` There are way better ways to do deployments other than `cmd`. for cmdline, see powershell usages [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/Get-EBEnvironment.html) , [here](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) and also [here](https://aws.amazon.com/devops/#:~:text=AWS%20CodeDeploy%20automates%20code%20deployments,complexity%20of%20updating%20your%20applications.)

Comment: @Gerhard, thank you for the links! Looks like the AWS Developer Tools is a good option, although the Powershell route could be an option. I still need to create some kind of standalone engine where it will do the actual deployment. Can the AWS Developer Tools allow me to do this programmatically?

Comment: Yes. Powershell will be the tool, building the code to do what you want will depend on the skills of your developers.

Comment: Thank you again @Gerhard. Writing Powershell scripts looks daunting. Any good tools to create Powershell scripts that you would recommend? Besides that, I am definitely looking for someone who can help us do this.

Comment: From one scripting language to the next, it looks daunting until you learn and understand it, then it becomes second nature. What is your scope and for how big a corporation is the requirement for, as that will help determine what you really need to invest in this.